# Flatten in Drill DB

Tags: sql, apache-drill, mapr

I have a query which runs perfectly on SQL Server which uses Unpivot.Can some one please help to run this on Map R DB using Apache Drill.I am completely new to Map R.

```
    SELECT   *
    FROM * from Tbl1;
      UNPIVOT
    (
      Sales
         FOR Year IN (2005,2006,2007)
        ) AS P
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no PIVOT/UNPIVOT in Apache Drill yet. But the same behavior can be emulated using SELECT ...CASE expression.